# Redshift: Query Result Cache vs Query Compilation Cache

Tags: caching, amazon-redshift

This question is related to the result cache and query compilation cache in Redshift.

I am benchmarking my queries for execution time. I ran the same set of queries to test for query compilation cache yesterday and they ran in milliseconds. Today I tried to test the execution time again but enable session cache and check the execution time for subsequent run. the execution time today is much more than yesterday.

**Question**

- Does executing queries with result cache turned on have an effect on execution time?
- the same query with result cache turned off for session ran really fast than when cache result turned on, Why is this?
- What time frame or how many query runs does the query compilation cache stays?

[Benchmarking Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBg8n.png)

*P.S. I read a bunch of articles and posts regarding query compilation cache and result cache but did not find any concrete answer.*

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider query compilation time and results caching, they are completely different things.

The **first** run of a sql "template" runs slower as redshift has to optimize (compile) it.  the only way to clear this compilation is to restart redshift i think.

The results cache is completely different, if you re-run the exact same sql then the results cache will return the results if it is switched on.

e.g. for a given query

```
select * from table where xyz='example1';
```

This first run will compile the query, so it will take longer. this processes is dependent upon the complexity of the sql, very complex sql can take 30 seconds to compile.

If you have query results cache turned on, then a second run of the **exact** same query

```
select * from table where xyz='example1';
```

will probably take 100ms or less (excluding network time if the results are large)

However if you run a similar query such as 
    select * from table where xyz='example**2**';

This cannot use the results cache but CAN use the compiled version of the first query, so it will run efficiently.

if you were to run a different query such as

```
select * from table where xyz='example1' order by 1 desc;
```

Then no cache will be used and the compilation will need to happen.

So, for proper benchmarking, turn off results cache but discard the first run of any given query pattern.

Comment: So they are totally unrelated to each other right?
I ran the same queries w/ and w/o enabling result cache and the result looked different so I was wondering how that happened.

Comment: Queries that are answered from the result cache return _extremely_ quickly. Use this query to check if a query used a cached result: `SELECT * FROM svl_qlog WHERE query = 1234567;`. If the `source_query` column is populated it means the result came from the cache.

Comment: Hey Joe, Thanks for your answer. My question was does the redshift takes time to compile query whilst result cache is turned ON vs turned OFF.

Comment: compile cache and results cache are different things. if query hits the results cache then of course the compilation does not happen. if query does not hit results cache then it may need to be compiled, depending upon whether it is in the compile cache yet or not. If a query IS in the results cache then probably it is also in the compile cache, so a similar query would probably use the compile cache (but of course could not use the results cache unless it is EXACTLY the same as a previous query and the underlying data has not changed)